# Extending classes from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a gem, that declares the class `FulltextRow`

I created an initializer called hacks.rb were I open classes from different gems.

I added the following code:

```
FulltextRow.class_eval do
    ....
end
```

However, If I don't require the class I get the exception:

```
uninitialized constant FulltextRow (NameError)
```

But it works well If I do:

```
require 'fulltext_row'
FulltextRow.class_eval do
    ....
end
```

My question is:

Why do I need to require a class that is defined in a gem? Aren't they automatically required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would love to help you out but it's hard to troubleshoot this with the lack of information given. I do have two suggestions, though.

1) You should verify the gem is loading properly within the gem. What I mean is to have supporting tests that affirm that the gem is working as intended. I've had instances where my gem's classes were not loading because I wasn't setting up the file structure right or had a silly typo somewhere.

2) It is also possible that your gemfile has set to not load the gem automatically.

```
gem full_text_row, require: false
```

Good luck!